# How do I get the directory where the executable is located?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I got the filename like this:

```
_TCHAR filename[_MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,filename,sizeof(filename));
```

How do I remove the filename from this full path? Should I use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Windows shell API function [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this. Example usage is listed on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use VS++, you can use:

_splitpath and _wsplitpath functions to break apart path